# C# 4.0 Antlr4 run-time

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr4

Does any one knows, when is other non-java run-time especially C# 4.0 would be available.

Earlier Antlr 3.0 versions got run-times almost for all popular programming languages.

Comment: This question isn't a direct Q&A programming question and as such doesn't belong here, you'd be better off checking their website or contacting them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the alpha release 2 of the ANTLR C# target here: http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/downloads/antlr/2013-02-27-antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT.7z

Announced in the ANTLR discussion group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/1vhJja-k6NQ